# Deploy to different machine profiles using DAGster

Tags: deployment, dagster

Can I specify the machine or machine type I'd like to deploy each task/workflow in Dagster separately?

(e.g. Having an A->B DAG, make step A performed on a machine of type M_a, and have step B occur on a machine of type M_b)

For example, if I have some CPU-heavy task and another which is GPU-heavy, I'll probably prefer they would not be run on the same machine type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of version 1.4.11, and for [Amazon ECS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/Welcome.html), I didn't find a solution running in the scope of a task or a workflow, but [in the scope of a deployment](https://release-1-4-11.dagster.dagster-docs.io/dagster-cloud/deployment/agents/amazon-ecs/configuration-reference#per-deployment-configuration).

That could be sufficient assuming flows for different machine types would be deployed separately. (And flows using several machine types may be broken into sub-flows)